# How to bring the class or method to scope in Different file Jquery

Tags: jquery

Am having the below code to change the validation class at Runtime

```
$("#txtNewAttributes").focusout(function () {
        var attributeTextBox = $("#txtNewAttributes").val()
        if ($.trim(attributeTextBox) == "Height")
            $(txtNewValues).removeClass('alphaonly').addClass('numbersonly');
        if ($.trim(attributeTextBox) == "IATA" || $.trim(attributeTextBox) == "IACA")
            $(txtNewValues).removeClass('numbersonly').addClass('alphaonly');
    });
```

And as Expected class name changes as i see in firebug. But the **Numberonly** class is not applied and the function is not working as it is Out Of SCope i thought as it is in a diff file as a function below

```
function AllowOnlyNumbers() {
    $('.numbersonly').each(function (e) {
        $(this).keydown(function (e) {
            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
            return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || (key >= 37 && key <= 40) ||
                     (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
        });
    });
}
```

How can i access the above function in my **focusout** Func in Jquery ?

Thanks

Comment: if `AllowOnlyNumbers` is scoped to the window and included prior to your runtime code, it will be available.

Comment: Try using onblur instead of focusout

Comment: How ll i bring to scope ?bcoz currently itz not working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you first register the `keydown` handler and then depending on the value entered in `txtNewAttributes`, you set the class of `txtNewValues`. This will indeed not work because the `keydown` handler will only be applied to the elements matching your selector at the time you registered it.

To *attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future*, use [`jQuery.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

```
$('.numbersonly').live('keydown', function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || (key >= 37 && key <= 40) ||
           (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right. You mean i need change my entire function or how do i include Live here in my code ?

Comment: You just have to change the way you register your event handler. You are using `keydown` which only applies to elements matching you selector at the time you run it, you should use `live` instead. Please read the documentation, there are a lot of examples.

Comment: Thanks tis s what am looking for! But what will be my selector to use for live ?  can u share some 1 line code as am very new to jquery